# Android app becomes unresponsive to touch

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, touch

I have an app developed with Sencha Touch and phonegap. At one point, it downloads data from a server and, once it has received a successful response, it displays the next screen. I found, when bundling it up as an iOS app, that it would transition to that next screen, but not display anything, reporting low memory. So I simplified the layout of that next screen (the DOM structure was pretty complex) and it now works on the iOS simulators and on my iPhone.

However, in Android, I can see from the output of my console.log statements that it successfully retrieves the data and fires an event to display the next screen. It then sits around for ages before it displays that screen, even though my console.log statements show that the 'painted' event of that screen has been fired.

Eventually, the screen does show up, but all the controls on the screen are unresponsive to touch. Is it likely that I need to simplify the structure of that screen still further? As the iOS version received a low memory warning before I simplified the page structure, I suspect the Android version may have a similar problem, but I don't know how to monitor memory usage. In the Android version, shortly before the screen does eventually display I see the following in logcat:

```
UpdateFrameCache: pending style recalc, ignoring
```

And on the screen which is unresponsive, when I tap some (but not all) of the unresponsive controls, I see:

```
Got ACTION_DOWN but still waiting on stale event. Catching up.
```

Eventually, the app will just close itself, with:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xbbbadbeef (code = 1)
```

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform intensive computations in the UI thread, it might explain why it takes so long. 
Try using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) if you have some backgorund computations to do. Once they are done, update the interface in the UI thread.

Gordak

Comment: Thank you, Gordak. Developing the app with Sencha Touch and previewing in Google Chrome, it seemed to me it was a pretty lightweight UI, but it looks like you are right. AsyncTask looks like it's spot on. Thank you.